# How to do an in-place `expand` on a domain in Chapel

Tags: chapel

The [expand](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/master/builtins/internal/ChapelArray.html#ChapelArray.expand) command in Chapel returns a new domain. I would like to increase a domain by one kinda like

```
var d: domain(1) = {1..5};
writeln(d);
 --{1..5}
expand(d)(1);
writeln(d);
 --{1..6};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Chapel 1.15 there is no in-place option for the `expand` method on domains. You would need to assign the result of `expand` to the desired domain:

```
var eDom = {1..5};
eDom = eDom.expand(1);
writeln(eDom); // {0..6}
```

It doesn't sound like `expand` is what you want though, because `expand` will grow the domain in both directions in each dimension. To add one index to a rectangular domain, you can assign a domain literal to your domain:

```
var rDom = {1..5};
const hi = rDom.last + 1;
rDom = {rDom.first..hi};
writeln(rDom); // {1..6}
```

For irregular domains you can use the `add` method:

```
var aDom = {1, 3, 5, 7}; // an associative domain
aDom.add(9);
writeln(aDom.sorted()); // 1 3 5 7 9
```

Note that you cannot use the `add` method on rectangular domains. This is defined in section 19.8.6 in [version 0.983](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/latest/_downloads/chapelLanguageSpec.pdf) of the Chapel language specification.

Comment: With all due respect, creating a **new** instance of a domain if by far **not** an **in-place operation** required by O/P, is it? Is there any way to achieve a truly in-place extension?

Comment: Correct. It was my intention to indicate that there is currently **no** in-place growing operation for rectangular domains.

Comment: Also note: If your use-case involves adding an element to an array, you may want to use `array.push_back(element)` to accomplish an implicit domain expansion while adding the element to the end of the array. Alternatively, `array.push_front(element)` will add the element to the front of array.

Answer (score 1):

### A few [online experiments on `domain` expansion](https://tio.run/##fZJdS8MwFIbv@ysOeNPhlrgLd9Gyi7hEVtySsVZQRCRrOlrsF203FfG317SbZR3Dc5WTnDx5eIkfyjyI63ovC2hLWaCyREapOR7AFL7HCN3@2MZHEVVBnJqgYGDDxcIYXOYdbxhGRwz6RIWCz1ymSncn2OA/rHgYAhVL4nD9/PRPCtiTxzhlFASHO@HNQXcuONwT8H2D0ORUgmQpteBFvUKUVrbR0Zt9lO/K8G0j/fe@U3t2UD@z6zt1Hg6nzprNvMVzo0SZqzvaWB2lxgcpfbvz2l6Mu58ljIAAF3zkzokGDtv1o6vRJizJaqUXg6NLw@5qi6RS5uQ8WD1yT5yFC3tcavBqLZaOy7SiBWFV5RbGfvspkF/IL@RnCVaZX@JEllVQ4M0uiqsoLbHOMShSGeNZO02KZjqskvjqdEMb9J0ArqcwseGyUzPb5b/Vqdf1Lw):

some worked as documented, some not:

```
var      d: domain(1) = {1..5};
writeln( d );                      // SET {1..5}
//      {1..5}

var      e: domain(1) = d.expand(1);
writeln( e );                      // OK, DOMAIN d == {1..5} EXTENDED ON BOTH ENDS INTO {0..6}
//      {0..6}

var      AonD: [d] int;
         AonD.push_back(1);
writeln( AonD.domain );            // OK, DOMAIN EXTENDED INDIRECTLY ON DESIRED END INTO {1..6}
//      {1..6}

// var      f: domain(1) = {1..5}; // NEW {1..5} - A NON-SHARED, NON-USED ( NON-MAPPED ) DOMAIN
//          f.add(6);              // FAILS v/s A PROMISE IN: http://chapel.cray.com/docs/master/builtins/internal/ChapelArray.html#ChapelArray.add
//          f  += 6;               // FAILS
// writeln( f );
```